# Erro loading schemes from Eclipse - Mule IDE

Tags: esb, mule

i am attempting to create my first mule server but i get an error for any external scheme i try and include,

my Config file is as follows (working on Eclipse Indigo with mule standalone 3.2 installation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
      xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
                  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.2/mule-http.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.2/mule-vm.xsd">


    <flow name="ChatListener">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="eventTimer" repeatInterval="2000">
            <quartz:event-generator-job>
                <quartz:payload>Poll Chat DB</quartz:payload>
            </quartz:event-generator-job>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <component>
            <singleton-object class="com.TimeLineListener.ChatListener" />
        </component>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="ChatMsgs" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
    </flow>

    <flow name="TimeLineMsgSender">
        <composite-source>
            <!-- Incoming Chat Msgs -->
            <vm:inbound-endpoint path="ChatMsgs" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>

            <!-- Incoming SIEM Msgs -->
            <vm:inbound-endpoint path="SIEMMsgs" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>

            <!-- Incoming NMS Msgs -->
            <vm:inbound-endpoint path="NMSMsgs" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
        </composite-source>

            <!-- Tested OutPut endpoint -->
         <stdio:outbound-endpoint system="OUT"/>


    </flow>


</mule>

and the errors i recieve are:

1.
The prefix "stdio" for element "stdio:outbound-endpoint" is not bound.  mule-config.xml ‪/ChatTester‬   line 41 XML Problem

2.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'vm:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-inbound-endpoint}' is expected. mule-config.xml ‪/ChatTester‬   line 31 XML Problem

3.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'quartz:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":composite-source, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-inbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected. mule-config.xml ‪/ChatTester‬   line 17 XML Problem
```

any idea what i"m doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1.
The prefix "stdio" for element "stdio:outbound-endpoint" is not bound.      mule-config.xml &#8234;/ChatTester&#8236;       line 41 XML Problem
```

This one is easy: you're missing the stdio namespace declaration.

```
2.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'vm:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-inbound-endpoint}' is expected. mule-config.xml &#8234;/ChatTester&#8236;       line 31 XML Problem

3.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'quartz:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":composite-source, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-inbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.     mule-config.xml &#8234;/ChatTester&#8236;       line 17 XML Problem
```

For these ones: I don't know. Maybe due to the mix of "current" and "3.2" you're using in the namespace locations? Try only with "3.2" instead of current to see if it helps.

Otherwise, nothing visibly crazy in your config :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a problem of Eclipse and doesn't relate to your configuration. Hope this helps:
"Since Mule’s schemas are not split over multiple schema files, it’s safe to turn off this feature. In Eclipse’s preferences, go to XML > XML Files > Validation and clear the Honour all schema locations check box. Mule config files should now validate without errors again."-MuleSolf Blog.
For more details: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/overcoming-xml-validation-errors-in-eclipse-35/